# MySQL not downloading correctly

Tags: mysql

I downloaded the MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE and can't connect to local host. I tried to make a connection and when I 'Test Connection' I get hit with an error message of 'Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root' with 'Unable to connect to localhost' below it. I tried to find ‘MySQL’ in system preferences->services but it doesn’t come up. Someone suggested that means that it didn’t download properly but I don’t know why it didn’t download properly. I have tried to redownload it several times now and the connection issues keep happening. I am working on Windows. Someone suggested typing 'mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -p' into the terminal. Do they mean the command prompt? Then I tried typing 'netstat -lnp | grep 3306' into the command prompt and it said 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

If anyone has any help I would really appreciated it. I have been lost for several days now and have no idea why this isn’t working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that this might fix your problem,

- try to uninstall all the previous installation like workbench or xampp or any other app that you might use for MySQL, using revo uninstaller or IOBIT , something like that.
- Download xampp app from this link https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/8.0.0/xampp-windows-x64-8.0.0-3-VS16-installer.exe and then install it,[image]
  it will show a warning but hit ok and next.. and leave it finishing installation,

[image]
allow its access and hit start on them booth and see if thet work , on apache and MySql,
[image]

then to test it properly go to web address on local host http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ (after running the xampp apace and MySQL services)

As you see there it looks that everything is working fine,
[image]

- Now we start with workbench (close all services to make sure that
  they wont cause any error, just stop booth 2 of them)

[image]

I would highly recommend you the community version, on this link https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=499590  405MB file,
[image: You click next]
Click next,
[image: There is a warning but click yes]
There will be a warning about visual studio and python, but I guess it will be ok, you didn't mentioned that you are working with any of them

[image: Click on execute and finish them installing successfully]
Click on execute and finish them installing successfully.

[image: next]

[image]

Now you hit next and create a password ex: localhost123@MYSQL

[image: Hit next]
[image]

And hit execute,
[image: Continuing]

Execute and finish
[image]

And you start the workbench, meanwhile start the services of xampp and start workbench, running xampp it gives me an error,
[image: Error]

Go to task manager and kill this process as shown: [image: kill this task service] then close and reopen xampp, then start services, check on localhost to ensure and open workbench again,
[image: fixed]
and check it